# '00 Volvo S40 Idle surging

Tags: cel, volvo, surging

The idle surges when in neutral and park, but there is no noticeable surge in gear or reverse. The car has an automatic transmission, if that makes a difference.

I have to this point replaced the Fuel pressure regulator, done new plugs, cleaned the IAC and throttle body, replaced the MAP sensor, cleaned the MAF sensor and replaced the air filter, replaced the CVVT solenoid gasket and cleaned the CVVT solenoid.

I am getting (at last checking) an ODB-II code for "Camshaft sensor output incompatible", I don't have the code handy, else I'd list it.

How can I get rid of this strange surging issue and fix the one last lingering CEL code so I can get the car inspected (NYS inspection)?

Comment: Have you check for vacuum leaks?

Comment: I have checked for vacuum leaks and we have checked that the waste gate on the turbo moves as it should. it could potentially be the camshaft position sensor causing the CEL, but it is unlikely that this would resolve the issue with the idling.

Comment: The camshaft sensor could absolutely make it surge, *especially* when the car has variable valve timing.

Comment: @DrakeClarrisand most likely an electronic throttle motor as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the camshaft position sensor. A bad sensor often makes it surge during idle and make it stutter on low revs. Has the car lost power? Is it difficult to start?